# Learning Json scraping with R coming from Python

Tags: python, r, json, rstudio

I'm moving to R from python and am trying to use my python skills to become familiar with scraping json with R. I am having some issues viewing and scraping what I would like to. I'm pretty sure I have the For loops down but I am unsure on how to select keys and return their content. I have read some documents but being new to R its a little tough to understand. For this I created a quick script with python to show what I am trying to do in Rstudio.

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

start = '2018-10-03'
end = '2018-10-10'

req = requests.get('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/schedule?startDate=' + str(start) + '&endDate=' + str(end) + '&hydrate=team(leaders(categories=[points,goals,assists],gameTypes=[P])),linescore,broadcasts(all),tickets,game(content(media(epg),highlights(scoreboard)),seriesSummary),radioBroadcasts,metadata,seriesSummary(series),decisions,scoringplays&leaderCategories=&site=en_nhl&teamId=&gameType=&timecode=') 
data = req.json()['dates']

for info in data:
    date = info['date']
    games = info['games']
    for game in games:
        gamePk = game['gamePk']

        print(date, gamePk)
```

Below is what I have started with but I am having an issue understanding where I can view my json other than print data which locks up R. I would like to be able to view the dictionaries and keys as I go. The other question is how would i then add the key-values to a "vector? or df?" and write them out. I am familiar with exporting to a file but curious as to how I add the values to a df. Would that be bind? or would i not have to do that?

```
library(jsonlite)

start <- as.Date(c('2018-10-03'))
end <- as.Date(c('2019-04-15')) 


url <- paste0('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/schedule?startDate=', start,'&endDate=', end,'&hydrate=team(leaders(categories=[points,goals,assists],gameTypes=[P])),linescore,broadcasts(all),tickets,game(content(media(epg),highlights(scoreboard)),seriesSummary),radioBroadcasts,metadata,seriesSummary(series),decisions,scoringplays&leaderCategories=&site=en_nhl&teamId=&gameType=&timecode=')

data <- fromJSON(url)
```

To expound on my issue here is a further sample of where the struggle lies.

```
library(jsonlite)

start <- as.Date(c('2018-10-03'))
end <- as.Date(c('2018-10-04')) 

url <- paste0('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/schedule?startDate=', start,'&endDate=', end,'&hydrate=team(leaders(categories=[points,goals,assists],gameTypes=[P])),linescore,broadcasts(all),tickets,game(content(media(epg),highlights(scoreboard)),seriesSummary),radioBroadcasts,metadata,seriesSummary(series),decisions,scoringplays&leaderCategories=&site=en_nhl&teamId=&gameType=&timecode=')

data <- fromJSON(url)

date <- data$dates$date
game_id <- data$dates$games

game <- NULL

for (ids in game_id) {
  pk <- ids$gamePk
  game <- rbind(game, pk)
}
```

I figured the "pk" would be in 1 column but its in multiple columns and I receive a In rbind: number of columns of result is not a multiple of a vector length

Comment: Try `str(data)` to see how everything is structured. You can access components of the data using things like `data$dates$games`

Comment: May want to check out the lubridate package, R date types can be a pain in that they are quite different than other languages. Also remember vectors start at index 1.

Comment: `fromJSON` returns a normal (if usually pretty ugly) list. You can pull out a single element by subsetting; to get more, you'll need to get familiar with `lapply` and friends (or [purrr](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/)). [roomba](https://github.com/ropenscilabs/roomba) is an interesting (but young) project for automating this extraction step. Also check out [httr](http://httr.r-lib.org/), which offers a nicer (and considerably more powerful) request syntax in which you can input your query as parameters.

Comment: Also, RStudio's recent versions have a very nice list viewer built in; just call `View` on the response. It can even generate subsetting code for you.

Comment: Looking at this case, you may want to tell `fromJSON` not to simplify to data frame; it's going overboard on nested data frames, so `response <- jsonlite::fromJSON(url, simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)`. From there, you can pull out the non-nested data from `games` with `library(purrr); response$dates %>% map('games') %>% modify_depth(2, discard, is.list) %>% map_dfr(dplyr::bind_rows)`. To get the rest will be more work.

Comment: Ok, now i see gamepk. How would i get just gamePK into its own df?